# how to optimize sorting and joining of 1 million entries from two tables in sql database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

The tables are of `employee` and `employee_info`

**employee contains:**

1. emp_id
2. emp_name
3. List item

**employee_name contains:**

4. emp_address
5. emp_id
6. emp_telephone
7. List item

Both the tables contain approx 1 million entries.

What is the **FASTEST way to join and sort** these tables?

Is there a technology that can be used apart from sql?

Comment: The technology is called SQL :-)

Comment: I'm using sql but it is taking a lot of time by simple order by and outer join. please help.

Comment: If you add _indices_ to the right columns, in the right way, your joining and sorting operations could become dramatically faster.  Have you put an index onto any of your tables?

Comment: will it improve the performance because emp_id is primary key that is as it is indexed and both sort and merge are based on emp_id

Comment: emp_id being a primary key will help for your employee table but you should add another index for employee_name probably on emp_id but that will depend on the columns you are querying in connection to and most often.  Note indexes help performance but do eat up space so it will be a balance of your resources if disk space is limited

Comment: So really you are after the _fastest_ way not the _best_ way. Specific performance tuning advice is often platform specific, so I suggest you tag with the type of database (Oracle? SQL Server?)

Comment: and also post the actual SQL Statement you are using

Comment: Select * from employee Inner Join employee_info on employee_id=employee_info.emp_id Order By employee.emp_id .This is the sql query but it takes lot of time to execute .Any faster methods?

Comment: And what do you do with your million joined records afterwards? Do you need all columns? Currently I would think that client side is slower than server - you need to fetch many megabytes of data :(

Comment: Make sure there is an index on the keys you are using and for additional performance create a stored procedure. The stored procedure will cache the execution plan so it isn't calculated every time

Comment: could you suggest me with how to use sp for this case or which key to index in this please

Comment: Why do you write in comments `employee.employee_id` and in the question `employee.emp_id`? You should try to provide exact info about your real db structure and indexes and db engine used.

Comment: Sorry its employee.emp_id .I'm using ms sql

Answer (score 4):

> What is the FASTEST way to join and sort these tables?

**If you are sorting by `emp_id`...**

Index both tables by `emp_id`. This will allow for merge joins, which are by far the fastest join.

For `employee_name`, make sure your index covers all of the columns you want. Otherwise you have to pay for expensive lookup join to the underlying table.

```
CREATE INDEX IX_employee_name_By_Id ON employee_name (emp_id) INCLUDE (emp_address, emp_telephone)
```

**If you want to sort by another column**

Now it gets hard. The index scheme above might work. Or you may find that by indexing on the sort column for one table and the join column on the other may be faster.

Again, make sure both of your indexes cover all of the fields you care about.

> Is there a technology that can be used apart from sql?

Yes, but I can't imagine why you would be willing to take the performance hit, let alone the added complexity.

Remember, SQL isn't "real code". Its more of a DSL that says what you want to happen without indicating how it should happen. Your database determines the actual algorithm to use based on lots of factors such as table size, indexes, value distribution (i.e. statistics), etc. As a programmer, you usually don't have the information needed to pick a better solution than you database comes up with.

More info: http://use-the-index-luke.com/

Comment: could you help me with how do i index the tables please? The code would help me a lot

Comment: Example and link to a training guide added.